# How to setup angular 2 material design 2.0.0-beta.2

Tags: javascript, angular, material-design, angular-material

I'm trying to use angular material design (2.0.0-beta2), but I cannot get it to work. For example, if I try to use

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput name="value">
</md-input-container>
```

With the following added to `app.module.ts`

```
    import {MaterialModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [ MaterialModule, ...],
    ...
})
```

But I get the following error:

```
'md-input-container' is not a known element:
```

Note: The component using the above code lives somewhere in my app a couple of modules deep!

When I also add `MdInputContainer` to the **declarations** I get a different error:

```
Type MdInputContainer is part of the declarations of 2 modules: MdInputModule and AppModule!
```

I think I'm getting close, but I'm missing something, any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you want to use material from a deeper module, just import it in that module.

Comment: You don't need to add in declarations array. Just import exactly to the specific module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use angular material components you need to import the `MaterialModule` in the module you are using it. Importing it only from parent modules won't recognize it.